# Navigation editor failed to initialize

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-navigation, android-jetpack

Suddenly, Android Studio started to prompt that to use the Navigation of Android Jetpack is necessary to install a module `android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:+.`. That is the whole module name.

Two problems. One, I already have it installed, version 1.0.0alpha-06 and second, if I attempt to install it will simply say it could not install.

The main issue here is that five minutes before this happened I DID use the visual editor of this, but it suddenly went like this.

I've already tried to clean the cache, invalidate and restart, but it decided to remain like this. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kotlin then add **-ktx** for kotlin support

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-alpha06"
```

Consider this dependency too:

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha06"
```

Another thing: consider using support library with version **27.1.1** or use the 28.0.0

Comment: I solved by using version `alpha01` instead of `06`, but it is still with strange behaviors. Nothing causes me more hatred than things that suddenly stops working.

Comment: The destinations are not being seen.

Comment: Are you using androidx?